# Installing Unity Asset Server on Debian has problems with postgresql

Tags: installation, debian, postgresql, debian-lenny

I used to have Debian Lenny (non-VPS, dedicated hosting) and Unity Asset Server (Unity3D's version control) was running smoothly. But recently I moved to Debian Squeeze (running on VPS) and I can't seem to install it.

I get the following output when trying to install.

```
cd: 68: can't cd to postgresql
home/apps/as/install.sh: 68: ./configure: not found
make: *** postgresql: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** UnityExtensions: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** UnityExtensions: No such file or directory.  Stop.
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/postgresql.conf.default': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/postgresql.conf.init': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/pg_hba.conf.default': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/pg_hba.conf.init': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/db_source.sql.bz2': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/db_upgrade_source.sql.bz2': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/reset_admin_password.sh': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/as_*': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `unity_build/unity_asset_server.sysvinit': No such file or directory
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc6.d/S00vzreboot
Initializing Asset Server database for the first time: Initializing Asset Server data directory...
    [FAILED]
```

I went through the Unity forums but I couldn't find anything useful. Do you know what the problem could be? PostgreSQL is installed (just reinstalled it to no avail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I built the package from the source and now it works. Apparently the ready-made package is not compatible with new Debian anymore.